# regex expression or in batch

Tags: regex, batch-file

How can I write a regex expression with OR in batch.
I have a file and I want to find "aa" or "bb".
The file contains these lines:

```
aa
bb
cc
```

This is the command I have tryed:

```
findstr /I /R /C:"aa\|bb" temp.txt
```

and

```
findstr /I /R /C:"aa|bb" temp.txt
```

Can anyone help me with the OR syntax in batch for writing regular expressions.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoted from the doc:

> FINDSTR does not support alternation with the pipe character (|) multiple Regular Expressions can be separated with spaces, just the same as separating multiple words (assuming you have not specified a literal search with /C) but this may not be useful if the regex itself contains spaces.

Reference: http://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html

Answer (score 0):

The default behaviour of findstr is to include all lines that match **at least** one of the conditions. So, your findstr line should be

```
findstr /i /c:"aa" /c:"bb" temp.txt
```